# Apache Rewrite keeping the original QueryString on the Rewrite URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem.

The follow code is my Apache configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^/page-(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:%{SERVER_PORT}/site/spaces/portal/page/$1 [QSA]
```

So, its OK. But, when I access my page like:

www.mysite.com/page-page?query=blah

It redirects the URL without the query=blah params.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It should work with or without `QSA`. Where is this rule placed? .htaccess or server config?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why they are missing, but you should be able to put them back with %{QUER­Y_S­TRING}.